# Wcf HTTP resultCode, Result and message in json format

Tags: c#, json, wcf

In Wcf i am getting data in that format

```
[{"status":{"message":"Login Successfull","result":1,"resultCode":200},"user":{"regId":6,"sessionId":"184b9524-abd1-4698-866a-f87c3270d44f","type":"S"}}]

but i want it in 
{"resultCode": 200,"message": "Login Successfull","result":,"user":{"sessionId":"CXNBVN543453VBNV654V4234G2F4V23423BN423NB24V2FSFDSDF6SFS6FSFBVNN","type":"parent","regId":""}}
```

i am using these class

```
[DataContract]
    public class LoginValidation
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string sessionId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string type { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int regId { get; set; }

    }

[DataContract]
    public class ResultStatus
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int resultCode { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string message { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int result { get; set; }
    }


    public class LoginStatus
    {
        [DataMember]
        public ResultStatus status { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public LoginValidation user { get; set; }
    }
```

How i can get data in that format

Comment: Post the code of your servicecontract interface as well.

Comment: public List<LoginStatus> doLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            List<LoginStatus> sLogin = new List<LoginStatus>();
            LoginValidation objValidation = new LoginValidation();
            ResultStatus objResult = new ResultStatus();
            dal = new dalService();
            bool res = dal.IsValidUser(username, password);
            try
            {
                if (res == true)
                {

Comment: objResult.resultCode = SucessResultCode;
                    objResult.result = SucessResult;
                    objResult.message = "Login Successfull";
      objResult.resultCode = SucessResultCode;
                    objResult.result = SucessResult;
                    objResult.message = "Login Successfull";

                    DataSet UserInfo = dal.getUserDetails(username);
                    DataRow dr = UserInfo.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                    string userType = dr["UserType"].ToString();
                    ClientId = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RefID"]);

Comment: sLogin.Add(new LoginStatus { status= objResult, user = objValidation }); else
                {objResult.resultCode = FailResultCode;
                    objResult.result = FailResult;
                    objResult.message = "Invalid sessionId or session expired";

Comment: sLogin.Add(new LoginStatus { status = objResult, });
                   // sLogin.Add(objResult);
                }
                return sLogin;
            }